Solving for maximum points using Taylor
aThe problem is simple: Solve for the maxima of the map $\mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$f(x_1, x_2) = x_1x_2 - x_1^{2} - x_2^{2} - 2x_{1} - 2x_{2} + 4$$
This is a scalar function. So, if any $a$ is a extrema, the gradient must vanish. We can simply solve for
$$gradf(a) = (D_1f(a), D_2f(a)) = (2a_2 - 2a_1 - 2, 2a_1 - 2a_2 - 2) = 0$$
, which leads to $a = (-2, -2)$. But then, the author concludes that The Taylor polynomial at $a$ of order $2$ must be of the form
$$f(x) = f(a) + (1 / 2)\langle Hf(a)(x - a), x - a \rangle$$
How is this so? It is easy to see that
$$\langle grad f(a), x - a\rangle = 0$$
Where's the remainder term? How is it $0$? Here's the original formula for remainder term in my book:

Here's the book reasoning before throwing the formula:


Look up the definitions. The Taylor polynomial of degree $k$ is a polynomial (of degree $\le k$). The remainder is what’s needed to get the actual value of the function.

@TedShifrin Edited my question to include the definition. Somehow I can't derive this trivially. It is easy to see that $a + h$ is replaced by $x$ and thus $h$ is just $x - a$

You need the multivariable analogue of this, and then you need to know that the Hessian gives the quadratic terms. But you still need to acknowledge that the remainder is not part of the polynomial.

@TedShifrin I'm lost here. Can you make it an answer? That's the only Taylor formula in my book besides the integral form. Thank you :-)
